# How to change .getElementById.value and assign each value to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I  have got 5 variables and a function:

```
function key(id){
    document.getElementById('songs').value
    =document.albums.names.selectedIndex
}
```

How do I assign each value (0,1,2,3,4) to each variable to show in a form when clicked on?

Comment: var1 = key(0)
.....
var5 = key(4) ?

You might consider clarify the question for a clear answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like that

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) for the documentation

Comment: Its nearly perfect! Do you know how to make it so only Volvo would come up when value=1 is selected as opposed to all of them?

Comment: @Tom Sorry, I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: @Tom If you want it to be empty for the first time, without a default value. Then you just want `selectedIndex = -1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to show value of selected option. this is your javascript function.

```
function getSelectedSong() {
    var songVal = document.getElementById("songs");
    var e = document.getElementById("select_song");

    var selectedSong = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    songVal.innerHTML = selectedSong;

}
```

and related html code will be.

```
<div id="songs"></div>
<select id="select_song">
    <option value="0">Song1</option>
    <option value="1">Song2</option>
    <option value="2">Song3</option>
    <option value="3">Song4</option>
</select>
<button onclick="getSelectedSong()">Pick Song</button>
```